# Permission to set default GIT branch of repo

Tags: azure-devops

which permission allows/denies to set the default branch of a GIT repository?
Me as an admin can do it but people with "Contributor" permissions cannot do it.
I would like to give them temporarily the right to set/change the default branch but I do not know which permission is the right one. The permission I could imagine to be the right one is "Force push (rewrite history, delete branches and tags)" or the "Create tag" permission.

Can you please help out?

Thank you

Comment: check this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/default-git-permissions?view=azure-devops

Comment: I already knew this page. But it does not mention what to enable to allow setting the default branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just refer to this doc: [Change your default branch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/manage-your-branches?view=azure-devops#change-your-default-branch).

> This step requires **Edit Policies permissions** on your Git repo.

**Edit Policies permissions**:

To set this permission, go `Project setting` => `Repositories` => Open corresponding repos and locate to the `Contributors` group you want to operate => Set `Edit policies` as **allow**:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. That was exactly what I was searching for.